# How to copy .png using FileSavePicker for wp 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

How to copy *.png from appdata:/assets/images using FileSavePicker. I find this example [File Save Picker - Save Edited Image (C# Metro app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051805/file-save-picker-save-edited-image-c-metro-app)  but it does not work.

i have this code:

```
private async void OpenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string path = @"\Assets\Logo.png";
        StorageFolder folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(path);

        // Show the picker
        FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
        // Set the file that will be saved
        savePicker.SuggestedSaveFile = file;
        savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "Logo";
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("PNG", new List<string>() { ".png" });
        savePicker.PickSaveFileAndContinue();



    }
```

but he saves the file to 0 bytes

Comment: Is it to copy or to save?

Comment: I need to save the application to your phone

Answer (score 0):

Did you try out the sample from msdn? Where did you go wrong withe one you found?

```
FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
// Dropdown of file types the user can save the file as
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Plain Text", new List<string>() { ".txt" });
// Default file name if the user does not type one in or select a file to replace
savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New Document";
```

Source:

- [Reference from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker.filetypechoices.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Save image in windows phone 8.1 using FileSavePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805757/)

Comment: And where to write a file to save? Your code keeps file size 0 bytes (

Comment: You could save it your local folder: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150592.aspx#wedge & have a look here for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048626/filesavepicker-saving-0-bytye-file-windows-phone-8

Comment: the first link has no instructions where to write the path of the file that you want to save

Comment: You mean the comment which is in the above comment or the answer?

Comment: I mean the comment above

Comment: So what does this `savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.LocalFolder;` states in that post?

Comment: Seems like here it has been worked out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571152/how-to-save-existing-storagefile-using-filesavepicker